# how to retrieve a specific get data in htaccess and pass it on rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a single get data (affid) that i want to retrieve using .htaccess but i don't know how to do it. Can you help me out?

Here is an example of links:

```
mysite.com/searchmembers?affid=1001
mysite.com/profle/123?affid=1002
mysite.com/videos/567?affid=1003
```

Another thing that might give a problem is these links already have been rewritten on .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^searchmembers? index.php?task=searchMembers
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)? index.php?task=viewProfile&id=$1
RewriteRule ^videos? index.php?task=videos&id=$1
```

i just want to retrieve the affid and add it to the links like this:

```
RewriteRule ^searchmembers... index.php?task=searchMembers&affid=(data retrieved)
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)... index.php?task=viewProfile&id=$1&affid=(data retrieved)
RewriteRule ^videos? index.php... task=videos&id=$1&affid=(data retrieved)
```

i know i could add it on htaccess for each of these links but if there is an easier way to do this then it would be a great help. thank you for any response that i will receive!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^searchmembers$ index.php?task=searchMembers [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ index.php?task=viewProfile&id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^videos/(.*)$ index.php?task=videos&id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

If you just need to append a new query parameter (like `task` here), any existing query parameters can be appended automatically using the `[QSA]` (Query String Append) flag. I've also corrected the regex used in your `RewriteRule`s. The use of `?` is incorrect.

Comment: hi. i didn't know that i will receive the correct answer as fast as this. thank you so much. But is there any other way, rather than adding the [QSA] to make this affect all of the links in mysite? by the way I appreciated your answer. thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've understood you clearly but unless you're rewriting a particular URL without `[QSA]`, you wouldn't lose `affid`. If you meant that once `affid` is received, it should be appended to all the links in the page; save it in the session or use cookies instead.

Comment: i guess there is no other way around. i better use this one. thank you so much!